# error: There is no SDK with the name or path 'iphoneos'

Tags: iphone

I have downloaded a sample and when I try to run it I get that error, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the iOS SDK installed, and not just the OS X SDKs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The XCode project file you're trying to open is referencing a version of the iOS SDK that you either don't have installed or don't have in the anticipated location.  This should be easily fixed by updating the project file to reference a version of the SDK available on your local machine.

XCode 4

- Open the XCode project
- In the left hand navigation pane open the project file
- For both your project and targets open the build settings tab
- Look for the 'Base SDK' setting and set it to the desired version

Older Versions

- Open the Edit menu
- Open Project Settings
- Same as XCode 4 instructions - set the 'Base SDK' to your desired version

Comment: i have checked the project settings -> Base SDK and i found that its value is "iphoneos" ???

Comment: Ok i understand, i changed it to my current iOS SDK version (in my case 4.0) and it worked, so thx a lot friend :)

Comment: It should reference a particular version i.e. 'iOS 4.3' or allow you to automatically use the latest version 'Latest iOS'.  Do you have alternative options in the drop-down menu?